# xcopy not accepting a relative path as source parameter on certain computers

Tags: batch-file, relative-path, xcopy

I'm trying to use xcopy to copy the contents of a directory

```
xcopy /e /q ".\dlls\*.*" "%programfiles(x86)%\foo" >> TEMP
xcopy /e /q dlls "%programfiles(x86)%\foo" >> TEMP
xcopy /e /q ".\dlls" "%programfiles(x86)%\foo" >> TEMP
```

All of the above work on two of my machines (windows 7 64bit).
But on two peers' laptops (windows 7 64 bit and windows 8 64bit) they return

```
file dlls not found
```

or (in the case of the first one)

```
file *.* not found
```

Can someone shed some light here? The only difference I can see between the machines is possibly permissions. But I don't see how that would affect xcopy's ability to recognize a local path.

Comment: what is the output of `dir dlls /b` ?

Comment: @nephil12 Well that tells me what the problem is. For some reason the batch script starts in the dlls folder even though it's run from the parent. From the first line of the batch file running dir outputs the contents of dlls.

Comment: I'll try to figure out how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

add cd .. OR cd C:\full\path\to\parent\of\dlls OR replace all mention of dlls with .

```
;)
```

Comment: but that will only make it work on the computers it's currently broken on. It works on some computers and your changes would break it there, no?
I'd love to know why the batch file doesn't keep the location it's run from as it's pwd.

Comment: the second option should work with all computers... post your code by either editing or putting it on pastebin.com or github or some such alternitive, and I'll take a look.

Comment: I can't use absolute paths since the location won't be constant.
My code can be shrunk down to the single xcopy line and still reproduce the problem

Comment: got o the dir that the file is in, and execute this. `cd&where file.bat&cd..&for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir dlls /s /b') do cd "%~dpi\.."&cd&file.bat`

Comment: post the output of that and if it works, I'll edit my answer to suit.